# How to mock the RestTemplate getForObject

Tags: mockito, spring-resttemplate

I am not able to mock below piece of restTemplate getForObject , Its giving assertion errors when i run my test case , can some one help me how to mock?.

### ServiceClient.class

```
String localizationDetails = getRestTemplate(RestClientEnum.LOCALIZATION_ZIP.getValue())
                    .getForObject(localizationUrl, String.class);
```

### Test class

```
@Test
    public void validateZipCodeTest() throws Exception {
        String zipCode = "98011";
        when(restTemplate.getForObject(ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                String.class)).thenReturn(xmlString);
        zipCodeDetails = serviceClient.validateZipCode(zipCode);
        assertNotNull(zipCodeDetails);
}
```

### Error

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(any(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(any(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it's usually a bad practice to [mock code one doesn't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own). The tests that have those mocks usually end up being difficult to understand and not testing anything of value.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem exactly:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

```
when(restTemplate.getForObject(
    ArgumentMatchers.any(),            // a matcher
    String.class                       // NOT a matcher
)).thenReturn(xmlString);
```

You can use matchers for *none* of the arguments (all values must exactly) or use matchers for *all* of the arguments. You cannot use matchers only for some.

The [docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) are quite explicit about it and showcase your example almost exactly:

> **Warning on argument matchers:**
>
> If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>
> The following example shows verification but the same applies to stubbing:
>
> ```
> verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), eq("third argument"));
> //above is correct - eq() is also an argument matcher
>
> verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), "third argument");
> //above is incorrect - exception will be thrown because third argument is given without an argument matcher.
> ```

How to fix? Use matchers for all arguments:

```
when(restTemplate.getForObject(
    ArgumentMatchers.any(),            // a matcher
    ArgumentMatchers.eq(String.class)  // also a matcher now
)).thenReturn(xmlString);
```